# Group customer by Turnover Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to group our customers based on their turnover according to the criteria below.

```
**AAA**: +50.000 EUR
**A**: 20.000 - 50.000 EUR 
**B**:10.000- 20.000 EUR
**C**: 5.000 - 10.000 EUR 
**D**: 0 - 5.000 EUR
```

I have tried using *if(calculate(sum(*
But it i can't get it to return the correct all the time. For some it returns the correct like AAA for turnover above 50000 but it also retunrs AAA for some customers below 50000.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this writing calculated column using `SWITCH` DAX function

```
Column = SWITCH(TRUE(),
Table([turnover]) > 50, "AAA",
20 <= Table([turnover]) <= 50, "A",
10 <= Table([turnover]) <= 20, "B",
5 <= Table([turnover]) <= 10, "C", "D")
```

Comment: if issue got resolved then accept answer and upvote